# Showing keyboard below a supportmapfragment in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, whatsapp, supportmapfragment

i would like to have a layout where i display a supportmapfragment and right under it a texbox where users can enter their text.

When the textbox has a focus i would like to show the keyboard (exactly like whatsapp does).

The problem im facing is that the map is taking all the space left, no matter if i use a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.
What i have managed to do so far is actually putting the textbox and the send button over the map, but not under. And even if i activate the keyboard, it doesnt really appear at all.

Thanks,

Comment: tried fixed height EditText and layout_weight of 1 and layout_height of match_parent to the support fragment ?

Comment: I meant inside Linearlayout with mapfragment having layout_weight of 1 and layout_height of match_parent and having edittext as its sibling with layout_height="60dp"(for example)